# Click button repeatedly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a button (id="next") inside a form which is needed for going through some records downloaded from server. Each time it is pressed a new record is presented inside my form. The button is not addressed to the server; everything is already downloaded and stored into client. My problem is if someone clicks the button repeatedly and fast, it shows up the window "Save Image". This happens only with Mozilla, not with IE11 and Chrome. Do you have any idea for preventing the window to popup?

```
<div class="search_button" id="next" title="Go for next"><img src="img/next.png"></div>
```

I 've tried the following; results are better, however not satisfactory:

```
$("#next").on('click', function() { 
      $("#next").css("pointer-events","none");  
      setTimeout(function(){ $("#next").css("pointer-events","auto") }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `next.png` as a background of `div#next`.

And `#next` should have CSS `user-select: none`.

Comment: Making next.png background is enough